# ImportError: cannot import name from 'rwrap'

Tags: python, import, python-import, import-module

very beginner here. I'm encountering an error when importing the package rwrap (pip install rwrap).

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import geopandas as gpd

import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import cm

import geoplot as gplt
import geoplot.crs as gcrs

from tqdm.auto import tqdm

from rwrap import eurostat
```

and here is the error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 15>()
     11 import geoplot.crs as gcrs
     13 from tqdm.auto import tqdm
---> 15 from rwrap import eurostat

ImportError: cannot import name 'eurostat' from 'rwrap' 
(C:\Users\Alberto\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\rwrap\__init__.py)
```

no idea what is going on, as I ran the same code on another computer and it works normally.

Also, the package seems correctly installed as if I run:

```
import sys
'rwrap' in sys.modules
```

I get "True"

Any ideas? Thank you.

Edit:

[Rwrap](https://pypi.org/project/rwrap/) is a package to integrate R modules into Python. So, I'm trying to call the "eurostat" module to download data and shapefiles from eurostat. I have also tried previous versions of the package with no success, a more likely possibility is that the package is not fully compatible with Python 3.10 (is there a way to downgrade it without uninstalling?)

If I run

```
import rwrap  
print(dir(rwrap))
```

eurostat is actually not in the output list...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I have never heard of this `rwrap` module and can't guess that it's used for. Why do you expect it to provide something called `eurostat`? To answer this for myself, I would start by reading the documentation. If it works on one computer but not another, one possibility is that it is a different version of the library, and that the `eurostat` functionality was only added in a recent version (or, less likely, *removed* in a recent version). The documentation should also help you figure this out.

Comment: I assume you mean [this](https://pypi.org/project/rwrap/) `rwrap`?

Comment: `eurostat` module is imported via rpy2 using rwrap, so you will not see the modules listed with dict, as its a runtime eval. Have you installed R and all the required dependencies correctly ?

Comment: You're right. I hadn't realized I had to download the eurostat module in R, first. Thank you. How can I flag your answer as correct?

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas?

Your error

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 15>()
     11 import geoplot.crs as gcrs
     13 from tqdm.auto import tqdm
---> 15 from rwrap import eurostat

ImportError: cannot import name 'eurostat' from 'rwrap' 
(C:\Users\Alberto\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\rwrap\__init__.py)
```

looks for me like you have `rwrap` (it even give you path to .py file for it), but there is not `eurostat` available in `rwrap`. Please run following snippet

```
import rwrap  # should not cause any errors or exception
print(dir(rwrap))  # should show list of elements available
```

Then write if `eurostat` present in list?

Comment: Please keep in mind that Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum; the answer section is for attempts at a properly worked-out answer, not requests for more diagnostics.